# Access AngelList API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, omniauth

I'm trying to access the AngelList API for a non user facing app. I managed to do so [through curl](https://angel.co/api/oauth/faq) but I want to automate it in Rails. How do you use oAuth strategies for that purpose? And where do you store the access token (there is no session)?

I would appreciate if someone could give me all the code needed (including controller and routes) so I can use an [oAuth strategy](https://github.com/jacquescrocker/omniauth-angellist) like the one below to fetch records for instance from `GET https://api.angel.co/1/startups/1` anywhere in my code.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :angellist, ENV['ANGELLIST_KEY'], ENV['ANGELLIST_SECRET']
end
```

Comment: OAuth is for signing up / logging in users, so are they doing it via a front-end application since the RoR site is a non-user facing app? If so, I'd recommend doing the oAuth on the client-side rather than the server side.   If you're trying to access the database to fetch records rather than authorization, have you tried the Ruby wrapper for the Angellist API?  See: https://github.com/paulsingh/angellist-api

Comment: Yes, the app is non-user facing. But how do I obtain the bearer token needed for that gem? I can do it manually through curl (https://angel.co/api/oauth/faq) but I guess these tokens expire so I'd have to do this manually all the time?

Comment: OAuth is for users logging in so that doesn't seem to be what you're looking for due to the stress on non-user facing app (unless I'm mistaken).   Instead you want to use an API key - https://github.com/paulsingh/angellist-api. If it isn't want your looking for, can you provide some details on what you're trying to do (ex: a use case).

Comment: You're absolutely right. But I think AngelList offers no other way of authenticating than oAuth: https://angel.co/api. Also, the gem https://github.com/paulsingh/angellist-api says you need a bearer token with a link to here http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html, which seems to only be obtainable through oAuth, correct? I don't want to use oAuth but I can't see another option or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on the angelist-api? The configuration link sends you to AngelList's API section where you create a token for your app.  Here's an open-source project where I'm grabbing data from AngelList. https://github.com/acpk/startupri via my app's API token.

Comment: You're awesome man, I didn't see that they provide a persistent token. Thanks so much. So you can either put in your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as correct or I delete this question, what do you prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access AngelList in your application, you can:

1. Use the AngelList API Ruby Gem

   gem install angellist_api
2. Sign up for AngelList if you haven't already and visit their API documentations (see [Angel.co/api](https://Angel.co/api)). On their API page, you can create a "token for your application" by registering your app.
3. Create a RoR initializer file with your API key.  I recommend using the Figaro gem or now RoR's standard .env file to set your variable for development, testing, production and staging if applicable.

Bonus: You can also do it manually without the gem by creating an ENV that contains your API key in the AngelList API URL.  If you're going to call records as you mentioned and potentially save them to your database, you can use:

```
def self.getAngellist
    response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(ENV["ANGELIST_API_URL"]))
    data = response.body
    parsed_response = JSON.parse(data)
    parsed_response["startups"].each do |startup|
      if Startup.where(:foreign_id => startup["id"]).blank?
        unless Startup.name == startup["name"]
          e = Startup.new(:foreign_id => startup["id"], :name => startup["name"], :description => HTML_Truncator.truncate(startup["product_desc"], 50), :url => startup["company_url"], :youtube => startup["video_url"], :facebook => startup["facebook_url"], :twitter => startup["twitter_url"], :linkedin => startup["linkedin_url"], :crunchbase => startup["crunchbase_url"], :angellist => startup["angellist_url"])
          e.save
        end
      end
    end
  end
```